# Properly load-file for interactive Common Lisp development

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

I would like to know, what is the common approach to common-lisp interactive development in emacs (i use sly, but i think the slime instructions should be the same)

say i have this file:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload :closer-mop))

(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage :shapes
  (:use :closer-common-lisp-user)
  (:export #:rectangle))

(in-package :shapes)

(defclass rectangle ()
  ((height :initform 0.0 :initarg :height)
   (width :initform 0.0 :initarg :width)))
```

which is quite simple.
Evaluating it experssion by expression seems to be ok, while loading the whole file (C-c C-l) gives me the following error:

```
The variable SHAPES:RECTANGLE is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

stripping it down to

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage #:shapes
  (:use #:cl-user)
  (:export #:rectangle))

(in-package #:shapes)

(defclass rectangle ()
  ((height :initform 0.0 :initarg :height)
   (width :initform 0.0 :initarg :width)))
```

doesn't make any change.

compile-and-load (C-c C-k) doesn't work either, leaving me with:

```
; in: DEFCLASS RECTANGLE
;     (SHAPES::DEFCLASS SHAPES:RECTANGLE NIL
;      ((SHAPES::HEIGHT :INITFORM 0.0 :INITARG :HEIGHT)
;       (SHAPES::WIDTH :INITFORM 0.0 :INITARG :WIDTH)))
; 
; caught COMMON-LISP:STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: SHAPES::DEFCLASS
```

i see that `defclass` can't be properly resolved to from `cl-user:defclass`, but can't see the way to fix it.

I wonder what am i missing?
And what is the common flow for developing interactively in emacs?

Comment: The `closer-common-lisp-user` package doesn't export the built-in Lisp functions. You need to `:use #'common-lisp` as well.

Comment: maybe there is a package CLOSER-COMMON-LISP instead

Comment: wow. Both of your answers are correct (no surprise). Could you please move them to actual answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that you are confusing two ways that packages can be used in CL.  A package generally serves one, or both, of two purposes:

1. it can export a number of symbols, providing some kind of interface to functionality;
2. it can be a package in which other packages are used or from which symbols are imported, but which does not export any symbols (unless it is also a type 1 package).

There is no formal distinction between these types of packages, but there very often is an informal distinction.  Packages which are of the second type above are often called `*-USER` with the canonical example being the `CL-USER` package.  They often (but not always) serve as places for scratch work.

So what you are doing is defining a package whose use list is such a user package.  You can see that this is not going to work by simply looking at the external symbols of this package.  From your second example:

```
> (do-external-symbols (s (find-package "CL-USER"))
    (print s))
nil
```

In other words, `CL-USER` exports *no symbols at all*.  This means that your `SHAPES` package will initially not have access to any symbols at all, and in particular *none* of the CL symbols will be present.

Well, the language defines a canonical 'type 1' package, which is `CL`: the whole purpose of this package is to export the symbols which define the Common Lisp language, and only those symbols.  So the definition of the `SHAPES` packages in your second example should be

```
(defpackage #:shapes
  (:use #:cl)
  (:export #:rectangle))
```

(Note that `SHAPES` is a type 1 package: it is providing some functionality in the form of `SHAPES:RECTANGLE`, and presumably is therefore intended to be used by other packages.)

Closer to MOP provides two packages which mirror the standard `CL` and `CL-USER` packages:

- `CLOSER-COMMON-LISP` is like `CL` except that various symbols are replaced by ones defined by Closer to MOP, and there may be additional MOP symbols;
- `CLOSER-COMMON-LISP-USER` is like `CL-USER`: it's a package intended general use, which users `CLOSER-COMMON-LISP` but which does not export any symbol at all.

Comment: Right. That whole question was based on my misconception user *-user packages reexport values. Thanks!

Comment: @leetwinski: yes.  Sorry if my answer was overlong as I suspect you didn't need anything that complicated: I wanted to try and leave something which might be useful in future.